# PyCharm - from turtle import * -- Giving unused import reference

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, turtle-graphics

PyCharm isn't importing/resolving properly. The code runs okay, but it isn't getting code completion, and is flagging up as errors (red squiggly lines).

The code that demonstrates this is as follows:

```
from turtle import *

forward(40)
right(45)
forward(80)


import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.forward(40)
t.right(45)
t.forward(80)
```

And a picture that demonstrates the issue in PyCharm:

https://prnt.sc/ni9dvk

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem? It's pretty annoying to not be able to use `from X import Y`.

Comment: Do not use `from X import *`, regardless of what package `X` is or what its documentation says, It will only lead to bugs later down the road. Also, Pycharm is warning  that `import turtle` violates PEP8 by having an `import` statement not at the top of the script.

Comment: I know about the `import turtle` PEP8 thing, it's only there to demonstrate that it works fine for normal imports, so it's likely not an interpreter error..? Either way, the point still stands... The `from turtle import *` should work, and code completion for the `forward(someInt)` should work properly... Instead IDE alerts get thrown up, even if Python is fine running it.

Comment: If you run that program, it runs as expected... Am I missing something? As far as I can tell, it's just PyCharm that doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, do not use `from X import *`, regardless of what package X is or what its documentation says, It will only lead to bugs later down the road.

**Why "star imports" should be avoided**

```
from turtle import *

def forward():
    print('forward')

forward(45)
```

What do you think will happen?

`turtle.forward` is overwritten by the locally defined `forward` function, and we will get an error `TypeError: forward() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

**Why it works in this case**

```
from turtle import *

forward(40)
```

To understand why the above works even though Pycharm says that `forward` is not defined we have to see how the `turtle` module is implemented, and then understand how Python imports work and how Pycharm checks for "definitions" of used names.

turtle.py

```
tg_classes = ['ScrolledCanvas', 'TurtleScreen', 'Screen',
               'RawTurtle', 'Turtle', 'RawPen', 'Pen', 'Shape', 'Vec2D']
_tg_screen_functions = ['addshape', 'bgcolor', 'bgpic', 'bye',
        'clearscreen', 'colormode', 'delay', 'exitonclick', 'getcanvas',
        'getshapes', 'listen', 'mainloop', 'mode', 'numinput',
        'onkey', 'onkeypress', 'onkeyrelease', 'onscreenclick', 'ontimer',
        'register_shape', 'resetscreen', 'screensize', 'setup',
        'setworldcoordinates', 'textinput', 'title', 'tracer', 'turtles', 'update',
        'window_height', 'window_width']
_tg_turtle_functions = ['back', 'backward', 'begin_fill', 'begin_poly', 'bk',
        'circle', 'clear', 'clearstamp', 'clearstamps', 'clone', 'color',
        'degrees', 'distance', 'dot', 'down', 'end_fill', 'end_poly', 'fd',
        'fillcolor', 'filling', 'forward', 'get_poly', 'getpen', 'getscreen', 'get_shapepoly',
        'getturtle', 'goto', 'heading', 'hideturtle', 'home', 'ht', 'isdown',
        'isvisible', 'left', 'lt', 'onclick', 'ondrag', 'onrelease', 'pd',
        'pen', 'pencolor', 'pendown', 'pensize', 'penup', 'pos', 'position',
        'pu', 'radians', 'right', 'reset', 'resizemode', 'rt',
        'seth', 'setheading', 'setpos', 'setposition', 'settiltangle',
        'setundobuffer', 'setx', 'sety', 'shape', 'shapesize', 'shapetransform', 'shearfactor', 'showturtle',
        'speed', 'st', 'stamp', 'tilt', 'tiltangle', 'towards',
        'turtlesize', 'undo', 'undobufferentries', 'up', 'width',
        'write', 'xcor', 'ycor']
_tg_utilities = ['write_docstringdict', 'done']

__all__ = (_tg_classes + _tg_screen_functions + _tg_turtle_functions +
           _tg_utilities + ['Terminator'])  

...
```

As you can see, it simply prepares some lists of strings (which are **names** of functions/classes/etc) then concats everything to a single list and assigns everything to the `__all__` global variable.

I will not go into much details about `__all__` (since there are several Q&A on SO on that topic, for example [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)), but basically it tells the interpreter what names should be available when doing `from X import *`.

When you are doing `from turtle import *` then using `forward`, `right` etc, they are available to use since their name is inside `__all__`, but Pycharm has no idea that they will be exposed by `__all__` at **runtime**.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that a bit. :) - Out of curiosity, is the only way for the methods to be detected by PyCharm to instantiate the object (as done in the second part of my example), or is there another, more sophisticated import statement I can use? --- [BTW: I'm brand new to Python, but have been around Java, .Net and PHP for over a decade]

Comment: @Jack_Hu You can do `from turtle import forward` but Pycharm will still not be able to know that `forward` exists. The best way will be to instantiate an object. That's how these functions are supposed to be used.

Comment: Ahh right. That's what I thought. I don't like the whole idea of using asterisks anyway. Instantiating feels a lot more familiar to me. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

What's going on here is that Python turtle is unusual in that it has two different interfaces, a *functional* one and an *object-oriented* one.  If you use the object-oriented one, everything should work fine:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

yertle = Turtle()

yertle.forward(40)
yertle.right(45)
yertle.forward(80)

screen = Screen()

screen.exitonclick()
```

The functional interface is there to make things easier for beginners:

```
from turtle import *

forward(40)
right(45)
forward(80)

exitonclick()
```

or:

```
import turtle

turtle.forward(40)
turtle.right(45)
turtle.forward(80)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

But you shouldn't mix the two!  As that is a primary source of turtle confusion.

The issue with PyCharm is that the turtle *functional* API is derived from the *object-oriented* API at load time, so it's not there for PyCharm to find when it scans the source file.  The turtle methods are all mapped onto the *default* turtle and screen methods are all mapped onto the *singular* screen instance.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from turtle import Turtle
```

it must work.

greetings.

Comment: It does not... Again, the code runs as intended, but PyCharm doesn't like it. IDE fail, not a Python fail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my question is more about why an IDE won't necessarily interpret the import statement correctly, or seemingly so anyway.